# Plotting four variables u = f(x, y, z) with ranges of x, y, z in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot four variables (x, y, z, u) in a 3D space.

Below I defined `u = f(x,y,z) = (x-y)/z` and ranges for `x`, `y` and `z`. 
Then I used the `scatter3` function for plotting.

But the `linspace` command only returned

```
u1 = f(x1, y1, z1) 
u2 = f(x2, y2, z2)
...
```

I wanted to plot my variables so that I would get values of `u` for all `x`, `y` and `z`, so as well as `u_i = f(x_i, y_i, z_i)`, I want:

```
u112 = f(x1, y1, z2) 
u121 = f(x1, y2, z1) 
...
```

**Which function do I need to use for this?**

---

Full code:

```
z = linspace(1,2,50);
y = linspace(0,0.5,50);
x = linspace(-1,1,50);
f = (x-y)./z;
scatter3(x,y,z,5,f,'filled')
for i=1:50
    if f(i)<0
        scatter3(x,y,z,5,f,'r','filled');
    else
        scatter3(x,y,z,5,f,'b','filled');
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your `x`, `y`, and `z` vectors to [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to have it generate points to fill the whole 3-D volume:

```
z = linspace(1, 2, 50);
y = linspace(0, 0.5, 50);
x = linspace(-1, 1, 50);
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(x, y, z);
f = (X-Y)./Z;
```

These will be 50-by-50-by-50 matrices. To plot them with [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) you will need to reshape them into column vectors using the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

```
scatter3(X(:), Y(:), Z(:), 5, f(:), 'filled');
```

If you'd like to plot negative values of `f` as red and positive values as blue, you can call `scatter3` like so and add a [jet](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jet.html) [colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) (no loops necessary):

```
scatter3(X(:), Y(:), Z(:), 5, (f(:) < 0), 'filled');
colormap(jet);
```

Comment: I was trying to color code my results, so that positive f values will be plotted in blue and negative f values will be plotted in red. Can you advise me on how to put index `i` to `scatter3`?

Comment: @Jennifer: I added a no-loop option to recolor your data.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've also been trying to see if I can further specify what colors `f` should be depending on its value, for instance to plot 0 < f < 10 in red, 10 < f < 20 in blue, etc. I see that I can put in `(0 < f(:) < 10)` in place of `(f(:) < 0)` in your code, but if I want to add additional ranges, that exceeds the number of arguments, and I was wondering if I can somehow add more colors at different ranges of f values?

Comment: @Jennifer: Your best option may be to adjust the colormap to your data. [This example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#buq1hym) shows how to create a colormap with 5 color ranges. You can also adjust the mapping with [`caxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html). This will probably be easier than modifying `f` before passing it to `scatter3`.